# Determing unsupported image formats for PDFBox

Tags: pdf, image-processing, format, pdfbox

I have spent a few hours trolling through the mailing lists and bug tracker for PDFBox(http://pdfbox.apache.org/), and I am trying to determine what would decide a supported /unsupported image format, and how to test for that format when it being used so that I can verify if there is an issue with the underlying document format when comparing scans from customer documents that we have attempted to extract images from.

I already found that the JBIG2 compression format was not supported via a few tickets that were submitted via its bug tracker (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1439), but I am struggling to determine what other types of images could potentially cause issues.

I checked their FAQs and documentation and I don't see any lists regarding this information.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you by any change find the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I went through their bugtracker but couldnt track anything else down besides this.